# Node doesn't start after adding extra column in CashSchemaV1 while using PostgreSQL

Tags: node.js, postgresql, liquibase, corda

Added an extra column xyz in CashSchemaV1. I am able to start node with H2 db,  but it gives the following error when using PostgreSQL:

```
[ERROR] 14:52:11+0530 [main] internal.NodeStartupLogging.invoke - Exception during node startup: Incompatible schema change detected. Please run the node with database.initialiseSchema=true. Reason: Schema-validation: missing column [xyz] in table [contract_cash_states]
```

Followed https://docs.corda.r3.com/database-management.html#database-management-scripts

Added the xyz column in https://github.com/corda/corda/blob/master/finance/workflows/src/main/resources/migration/cash.changelog-init.xml

```xml
<column name="pennies" type="BIGINT"/>
<column name="xyz" type="NVARCHAR(130)"/>
```

then added database migration scripts retrospectively to an existing CorDapp.
After this tried to start the node but getting following error:

```
[ERROR] 14:52:11+0530 [main] internal.NodeStartupLogging.invoke - Exception during node startup: Incompatible schema change detected. Please run the node with database.initialiseSchema=true. Reason: Schema-validation: missing column [xyz] in table [contract_cash_states]
```

CashSchemaV1.kt https://github.com/corda/corda/blob/master/finance/contracts/src/main/kotlin/net/corda/finance/schemas/CashSchemaV1.kt

```
@Type(type = "corda-wrapper-binary")
            var issuerRef: ByteArray,

            @Column (name = "xyz")
            var xyz: String

    ) : PersistentState()
}
```

Migration script generated cash-schema-v1.changelog-master.sql

```
--liquibase formatted sql

--changeset R3.Corda.Generated:initial_schema_for_CashSchemaV1

    create table contract_cash_states (
       output_index int4 not null,
        transaction_id varchar(64) not null,
        ccy_code varchar(3) not null,
        issuer_key_hash varchar(130) not null,
        issuer_ref bytea not null,
        owner_name varchar(255),
        pennies int8 not null,
        xyz varchar(255),
        primary key (output_index, transaction_id)
    );
create index ccy_code_idx on contract_cash_states (ccy_code);
create index pennies_idx on contract_cash_states (pennies);
```

Schema should be created with all the columns specified in CashSchemaV1

Answer (score 0):

Steps performed to add extra column : 
1)Added `<column name="xyz" type="NVARCHAR(130)"/>` in  cash.changelog-init.xml
2)Added `<addNotNullConstraint tableName="abc_states" columnName="xyz" columnDataType="NVARCHAR(130)"/>` in cash.changelog-v1.xml

Built the cordapp and then ran the node using this , node started successfully.